# Merge two or more rows in radgrid

Tags: asp.net, .net, merge, telerik, radgridview

I'm using Telerik RadGridView- Telerik UI and I want to merge two rows into one after summing their quantity columns.

Here's a picture of my gridview:

[image: Here's the pic of my gridview]

Comment: What is your data source? Could you show NeedDataSource event?

Comment: The data is loaded from Excel file and then shown to the RadGridView.
i don't use "NeedDataSource" event.
i just want to find a way to render the gridview to show them after merging quantities of the similar items

Answer (score 3):

I did this in one of my project, there are 3 different data field getting from data-source are merge in one label.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvRush" runat="server" SkinID="GridView" PageSize="30" //other event like on_sorting, OnRowDataBound, etc>
    <Columns>
    //Other columns
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Procedures" SortExpression="ProcDesc">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblProcedures" runat="server"><%# Eval("ProcLabel") %>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<%# Eval("ProcDesc") %>&nbsp;(<%# Eval("RequestProcessCount") %>)</asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle Width="150" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    //Other columns
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
    There are no Rush items found in the currently selected filtered view
</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
    // data source code
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer is you cannot. Telerik RadGridView is not responsible for merging row based on business logic; its job is just to display data provided to it.

It should be your business logic code to merge those rows.

Comment: Okay, understood and surely no built-in method for that in Telerik grid, but the problem is i want to loop through these rows of the Telerik grid and when i find similar rows, i sum their quantities up and add them as one row (the other columns don't change) that's my simple business logic.
so is there any way or even pseudocode i follow which can achieve that ?

Comment: You will have to manipulate the source, before you even assign to Telerik RadGrid.